# Reclass a landuse shapefile based on another shapefile using R

Tags: shapefile, r, land-use, rgeos

I have a landuse shapefile that I want to modify based on another shapefile.

In this [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7gq0jteufq0c2u/Rplot.png?dl=0) I have three classes in landuse shapefile A.

Say I'd know that everything within one of the small shapefiles, called B, outlined in black belonged to class four.

Is there a way to create a new shapefile C based on the landuse shapefile A and a new shapefile B that assigns class 4 to everything that falls in shapefile B's geometry?

I tried workarounds for that, substracting B from A and then combining them back together, but I couldn't find a method that adds both polygon fields together AND the attribute table without creating things like area.1, Class.1, area.2, Class.2 and so on.

I'm really stuck with this but I believe there must be a not-so-hard solution to this.

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jjkb2ius6udcq3h/example_files.7z?dl=0) are two example shapefiles, landuse and industry. 
I want to produce a shapefile where all that is covered by industry is classified as industry and the rest of the landuse stays the same

Comment: Can you supply this data or something similar? 80% of the time answering questions like this is setting up a dataset to work on.

Comment: All the files in that .7z file seem to have zero length, and the .7z file is only 197 bytes long which looks way too small to have any real data in it. Try again?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it, should work now!